# How to vectorize/optimize calculations that rely on prior rows

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, optimization, vectorization

I'm working on something where runtime is extremely important and the data we're working with is large, but basically the problem boils down to optimizing solving for series x where x1 is known and x = ax+b from the prior row. So for example, starting state:

```
a b x
1 2 3
3 1
2 2
4 8
1 9
```

and the end state would look like this:

```
a b x
1 2 3
3 1 5
2 2 16
4 8 72
1 9 81
```

because 3*1+2 = 5, 5*3+1 = 16, etc.

I tried working out the math of it and I ended up with:

```
b0 = x1
xi = sum(n=0 to i-1)(bn*product(m=n+1 to i-1)(am)
```

So for example for the 3rd row you'd end up with:

```
x3 = a1*a2*b0 + b1*a2 + b2 = 3*1*3 + 2*3 + 1 = 9 + 6 + 1 = 16
```

But computationally that seems to be worse than just calculating each x by looping over rows, something like this:

```
for i in range(2,len(df)):
    df.x[i] = df.x[i-1]*df.a[i-1]+df.b[i-1]
```

Is there an easier way to tackle this that I'm missing, or am I just dealing with a computationally expensive operation that I'll have to eat the cost of iterating? If the a term didn't exist the bn portion could be tackled via cumsum, something like:

```
df['b_cumsum'] = x1+cumsum(df.b)
```

but I end up hitting a wall when trying to include the a terms, especially since we end up needing so many different sets of products even within each sum term.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it can be vectorized because it's a rolling calculation. So, you're probably asking us to beat the loopy code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first calculate a rescaled *x*: *x*' = *x*/cumprod(*a*) using a matching *b*' = *b*/cumprod(*a*)

This can be done with vectorized operations as can the backtransform from *x*' to *x*:

```
ab = np.array([[1, 2],
               [3, 1],
               [2, 2],
               [4, 8],
               [1, 9]])

scale = ab.T[0].cumprod()
xp = 3+(ab.T[1]/scale).cumsum()
x = xp*scale
x
array([  5.,  16.,  34., 144., 153.])
```

Comment: This clearly works and looks like a very elegant solution, but do you mind explaining the math a bit? I get that scale is just cumprod(a) but how is xp correctly calculating x/cumprod(a)? Thanks.

Comment: @zachvac Think about it like this: If the scaling factors (the _a_ column) were all 1 then it would be easy. By rescaling _x_ the way we do we achieve precisely that. We have to use the cumprod of _a_ because the original scaling is cumulative. Once that is clear we only have to observe that _b_ has to be scaled in the same way as _x_ to preserve consistency.

Comment: sorry I definitely get the overall goal, maybe I spent too much time trying to derive the sums/products to understand how this works. As an example to solve for x5 I got: [a1-a4]*x1 + b1*[a2-a4] + b2*[a3-a4]+b3*a4+b4 where the brackets indicate a product of those terms. How are you able to only scale once with a cumprod from 1 to 4 when there are products of 2-4, 3-4, and then a4?

Comment: oh wait I worked it out and I see how it works, it's a cumulative sum of the cumulative products in the denominator, and the numerator cancels out all of the denominator in the 1st term, most in the 2nd, etc. I'm going to study this for a bit more but this was super helpful thank you so much.

Comment: ok so my explanation has been as such:
we always end up with cumprod(a)*x1 + b1*[a2-an] + b2*[a3-an] + ... bn
so x/cumprod(a) = x1 + b1/a1 + b2/a1-a2 + ... + bn/a1-an

So I definitely understand why it works, I just don't particularly understand the scaling explanation or how to possibly get to that solution without an extremely lucky guess. I guess realizing that [ai-an]/[a1-an] = 1/(cumprod(a) at i) would be the key it just seems like you got there in a much more intuitive way.

Comment: @zachvac Allow me to give it another try: Divide your recurrence equation  `x[n+1]=a[n]x[n]+b[n]` by `a[n]`: `x[n+1]/a[n] = x[n] + b[n]/a[n]`. Do this recursively, so level n+2-in matches level n+1-out: `x[n+2]/(a[n]a[n+1]) = x[n+1]/a[n]+b[n+1]/(a[n]a[n+1])`, `x[n+3]/(a[n]a[n+1]a[n+2]) = x[n+2]/(a[n]a[n+1])+b[n+2]/(a[n]a[n+1]a[n+2])` etc. Would that be an angle that makes it more intuitive?

Answer (score 2):

When I run into functions I cannot vectorize, but it needs to be efficient, I use `numba`. Which is a just in time compilation (JIT) module. Most of the times this can be even faster than the native pandas methods:

```
from numba import njit

@njit
def calculation(arr):
    result = np.empty(arr.shape[0])
    for idx, row in enumerate(arr):
        if idx == 0:
            result[idx] = row[2]
        else:
            row = arr[idx-1]
            result[idx] = result[idx-1] * row[0] + row[1]
    
    return result

df['x'] = calculation(df.to_numpy())
```

```
print(df)

   a  b      x
0  1  2    3.0
1  3  1    5.0
2  2  2   16.0
3  4  8   34.0
4  1  9  144.0
```

---

**note**: when you want to time it. Don't time it on the first run, since it did not compile yet. First run it once, then time it on the second run.